# Determining if a multivariable limit exists

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

The limit I need to determine is:
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{xy^2+\sin(x)x^2}{x^2+y^2}$$

So far I have determined by using multiple curve paths that the limit is $0$. To prove it, I have tried both the squeeze theorem and the $\delta - \epsilon$ proof methods, but can't get my head around it.

I'm thinking the squeeze theorem is the way to go, but can't determine which functions should bound it. All I have done is simplify down to $\frac{x(y^2+x\sin(x))}{x^2+y^2}$. Further than that, I don't know what to do.

Comment: If you are allowed to use polar coordinates, then let $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$. The limit will only be based on $r$ tending to $0$ and simplifies nicely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Squeezing is a good idea and polar coordinates are not necessary:

$$\left| \frac{xy^2+x^2\sin x}{x^2+y^2} \right| \leq |x| \frac{y^2 + \left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|x^2}{x^2+y^2} \stackrel{\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right| \leq 1, x \neq 0}{\leq}|x| \stackrel{(x,y)\to (0,0)}{\longrightarrow} 0$$